# github api - how to sort by pushed_at without having to fetch all repos first

Tags: git, sorting, github, repository, github-api

I'm working on an app that will interact with github, show your orgs, and all repositories filtered by the selected org.  By default, it looks like you just get repos by `created_at`, which means that oldest things show up first.  If I find out how many pages are in the request, I can query for the most recent first, but this doesn't ensure being sorted by `pushed_at`.  Is there no sort option for getting org repos sorted by `pushed_at`?  I'd like the most recently intereacted with repos to be shown first (sorting on my server or client side is fine, but it seems like I would need to get all repos first if there is no way to query for data sorted that way.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which endpoint you're using? It looks to me like the [list repositories endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) supports a `sort` parameter that can be set to `pushed`.

Comment: @Chris yeah, that would be useful : I'm using https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories, which only has a type param.  I've tried every flavor of sort I can think of hoping for something undocumented but to no avail.  Thanks for the question!

Comment: The search endpoints have sorting, maybe I can search for repos for a given org...